# Can't setup simple Node.js server

Tags: node.js, routes, authorization

I am super new to Node.js and the whole back end in general.
I am trying to set up simple node.js server to create authorization(admin, user) nothing special I guess.
When I try just to enter my server in browser using localhost:5000
I get this error.

```
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:5000/ 404 (Not Found)
```

Same story when using http://localhost:5000/auth/login or any other routing.
The weird part is that at the same time I am always getting message`server started on port 5000` in VSC terminal.

And also few times somehow I managed get message
`REG`  in VSC terminal.

```
router.get('/registration', async () => {
    console.log('REG')
})
```

But in browser console I am getting same error`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Please find my code attached below.
server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const authRouter = require('./authRouter')//yes
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const connectionString = 'mongodb+srv://Ivan:aldaron1@cluster0.fivve.mongodb.net/usersBD?retryWrites=true&w=majority'//yes
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(authRouter);
const start = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(connectionString)
        app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server started on port ${PORT}`))
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

start()
```

authController.js

```
class authController {
    async registration(req, res) {
        try {
            res.json("server works")
            console.log(" 123 ")
        } catch (e) { }
    }
    async login(req, res) {
        try {
            res.json("server works")
            console.log(" 123 ")
        } catch (e) { }
    }
    async getUsers(req, res) {
        try {
            res.json("server works")
            console.log(" 123 ")
        } catch (e) { }
    }

}

module.exports = new authController();
```

authRouter.js

```
const Router = require('express')
const router = new Router()
//const controller = require('./authController')


router.get('/registration', async () => {
    console.log('REG')
})
router.get('/login', async () => {
    console.log('REG')
})
//router.post('/login',)
//router.get('/users', controller.getUsers)

module.exports = router
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "node-server-ivan",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "my first node.js server",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.15",
    "node": "^15.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

Any thougs why it like that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http://localhost:5000/login? I don't see the "/auth" part of the path being defined in the code. Same with "http://localhost:5000/" there is no resource being served in your code for that path.

From what I see these are the only paths that should work.

- http://localhost:5000/login
- http://localhost:5000/registration

I'm also noticing your entry point filename is server.js. Maybe you need to update your package.json to reflect this instead of "index.js"?

Comment: I changed it accordingly you were right. Afterward, I was getting a message that it can't find server.js. Probably it saved somewhere else aside from package.json.  Afterward, I created a new project from scratch with an index.js file and but still getting this error ```localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:5000/ 404 (Not Found)```. And still in VSC terminal written that ```server on 5000 started successfully```

Comment: Did you try creating a route for "/"?

router.get('/', async () => {
    console.log('HOME')
})